# NextJS locale change with dynamic routes

Tags: next.js, next-i18next

Locale change works well in my next.js app, except for with dynamic routes. In the browser address bar I do get the transition from `http://localhost:3000/client/home/profile` to `http://localhost:3000/de/client/home/profile`, but the page gives a 404 error...

My dynamic page **[tab].tsx**

```
import router from 'next/router'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import {useTranslation, i18n} from 'next-i18next'
import {useEffect, useState, useContext} from 'react'
import {serverSideTranslations} from 'next-i18next/serverSideTranslations'

import Layout from 'layouts'
import {DB, PATH} from 'utils/constants'
import {GlobalContext} from 'utils/contexts'
import {Tabs, LanguageSelector} from 'components/ui'
import {ChartData, ChartDataPoint, UsageStats} from 'utils/types'
import {getData, toTitleCase, isClient, emailVerified} from 'utils/helpers'

const Docs = dynamic(() => import('components/client/docs'))
const Stats = dynamic(() => import('components/client/stats'))
const Profile = dynamic(() => import('components/client/profile'))

const Tab = ({tab}) => {

  const {t} = useTranslation()

  return (
    <Layout>
      <LanguageSelector />
      <Tabs
        basePath={'/client/home'}
        tab={tab}
        tabs={[
          {
            slug: 'stats',
            label: t('client.home.stats'),
            component: <Stats data={data} />
          },
          {
            slug: 'profile',
            label: t('client.home.profile'),
            component: <Profile client={client} />
          },
          {
            slug: 'docs',
            label: t('client.home.docs'),
            component: <Docs />
          }
        ]}
      />
    </Layout>
  )
}

export const getStaticProps = async ({params, locale}) => ({
  props: {
    tab: params.tab,
    ...await serverSideTranslations(locale)
  }
})

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  return {
    paths: [
      {params: {tab: 'stats'}},
      {params: {tab: 'profile'}},
      {params: {tab: 'docs'}}
    ],
    fallback: false
  }
}

export default Tab
```

I do the locale switching in my **LanguageSelector.tsx**:

```
import router from 'next/router'
import {i18n} from 'next-i18next'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'

import {Select} from '.'
import {LANGUAGES} from 'utils/constants'


export const LanguageSelector = () => {

  const [locale, setLocale] = useState(i18n.language)

  useEffect(() => {
    const {pathname, asPath, query} = router
    router.push({pathname, query}, asPath, {locale})
  }, [locale])

  return (
    <Select 
      borderless
      isSearchable={false}
      value={i18n.language}
      options={LANGUAGES.filter(language => language !== i18n.language)}
      onValueChange={setLocale}
    />
  )
}
```

Any ideas where my mistake is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `getStaticPaths` with in-build Next.js i18n routing then you also need to return locale key with your paths, like that:

```
export const getStaticPaths = ({ locales }) => {
  return {
    paths: [
      { params: { slug: 'post-1' }, locale: 'en-US' },
      { params: { slug: 'post-1' }, locale: 'fr' },
    ],
    fallback: true,
  }
}
```

[More info in the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/i18n-routing#dynamic-getstaticprops-pages)

Comment: Do you mean I should provide a path for `post-1` for every language that I use in my project explicitly?

Comment: You should provide locale for every path. And if some path has 2 locales then it should be 2 separate objects each with path and locale

Comment: No problem! Please mark the answer as accepted if you tested the solution and it solved your question

Comment: This does indeed work. I ended up using this: 
`const tabs = ['tab-1', 'tab-2'];` `const locales = ['en', 'de'];` `return { paths: tabs.reduce((arr, tab) => ([...arr, ...locales.map(locale => ({params: {tab}, locale}))]), []), fallback: false }`